# Preserving syntax highlighting of echoed html in a php if statement

Tags: php, ide, editor, echo, syntax-highlighting

I saw in other questions that this was possible, but simply dropping the quotes gave me an error (unexpected '<'). I would like the html code to highlight as does the php around it.

```
if ($loggedin)
{
//echoes the logged in header.
    echo <b>$user</b>
         <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php?view=$user'>Home</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php'>Members</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcfriends.php'>Friends</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcmessages.php'>Messages</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcprofile.php'>Profile</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rclogout.php'>Log out</a>;
}
```

I don't know if the solution involves which text editor or IDE I use, some small syntax mistake, or the overall structure of the code. I would just like everything to highlight nicely, even if this involves putting it in a separate file or what. I don't really know what templating is, but I'll use it if it's the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite like so:

```php
<?php if($loggedin): ?>
    <b><?php echo $user ?></b>
    <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php?view=<?php echo $user ?>'>Home</a> |
    <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php'>Members</a> |
<?php endif; ?>
```

Alternative Control Syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

You could also use short echo tags, so:

`<?php echo $somevar ?>` would become `<?= $somevar ?>`

Short syntax is only available by default in >= PHP 5.4. It can however, be enabled in lower versions. http://www.php.net/echo.

You can therefore, rewrite your snippet like so:

```php
<?php if($loggedin): ?>

    //echoes the logged in header.
    <b><?=$user?></b>
    <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php?view=<?=$user?>'>Home</a> |
    <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php'>Members</a> |
    <a href='phpscripts/rcfriends.php'>Friends</a> |
    <a href='phpscripts/rcmessages.php'>Messages</a> |
    <a href='phpscripts/rcprofile.php'>Profile</a> |
    <a href='phpscripts/rclogout.php'>Log out</a>;
<?php endif; ?>
```

This should preserve syntax highlighting for both PHP and HTML in your IDE.

Comment: This is so much better. any reason why this isn't standard?

Comment: It is widely used in MVC systems, there are also various templating  systems which attempt to abstract this and provide extra features. Checkout [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and Smarty. However, I prefer just using PHP as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the [**`HEREDOC`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax ?

```
<?php
if ($loggedin)
{
//echoes the logged in header.
    echo <<<HTML
     <b>$user</b>
         <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php?view=$user'>Home</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcmembers.php'>Members</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcfriends.php'>Friends</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcmessages.php'>Messages</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rcprofile.php'>Profile</a> |
         <a href='phpscripts/rclogout.php'>Log out</a>;
HTML;
}
```

---

This **edit** is especially for [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense).

### Syntax Highlighting Preserves with HEREDOC syntax.

[image]

Comment: what you have shown is not proper *HTML* highlighting. Neither heredoc should be used to output from PHP anyway

Comment: However, you can at least prove your words, so I remove a downvote